# How to render TWIG output to a variable for later use (symfony2)?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, render

Instead of doing this rendering of each slide in my TWIG like this (see line 6):

```
{# loop out the slides #}
{% for c in contents %}
    {% set i=i+1 %} {# increase slide number #}
    <div id="slide{{ i }}" class="slide" style="z-index:{{ i }};">
        {# the slide itself, rendered by it's own template #}
        {% include 'BizTVArchiveBundle:ContentTemplate:'~c.template~'/view.html.twig' with {'contents': c, 'ordernumber': i} %} 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

...Instead I would like to keep all of that logic in the controller, to just deliver to the view an array of ready slides. How can I do something like this (see line 9):

```
    //do stuff...
    foreach ($container->getContent() as $c) {
                $content[$i]['title'] = $c->getTitle();
                $content[$i]['sort'] = $c->getSortOrder();
                $content[$i]['data'] = $c->getData();
                $content[$i]['template'] = $c->getTemplate()->getId();
                $content[$i]['duration'] = $this->extract_seconds($c); 

                $content[$i]['html'] = $this->render('BizTVArchiveBundle:ContentTemplate:'.$content[$i]['template'].'/view.html.twig', array(
                    'contents'=> $content[$i],
                    'ordernumber' => 99,
                ));
    }
```

All it gives me at the moment (the contents of $content[$i]['html']) is

```
{"headers":{}}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's better if you [include the template in the template](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#including-other-templates), this way you keep the templating rendering in the view layer and the logic in the controller layer.

But well, if you really want it...

You can use 2 services to do that: `twig` is using the `Twig_Environment` or `templating.engine.twig` which is a templating layer build in Symfony2 for Twig, this can be easily switched ot `templating.engine.php`.

If you use the `twig` service, you can see [the twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html) on how to use it:

```
$template = $this->get('twig')->render('/full/path/to/Resources/views/'.$content[$i]['template'].'/view.html.twig', array(...));
```

If you use the `templating.engine.twig` service, see [the templating docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/introduction.html) on how to use it, which is almost exact the same as the `Twig_Environment`.

Comment: How can I know what to specify the path in relation to? Like "where am I" when I start typing the path, am I in www? in my app folder? am I in my sym2project/web like usually (run from app.php?)?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson you can use the `__DIR__` constant, which is the dir of the PHP file that uses that constant. Or you can use a template resolver (not sure how that service is called) to resolve to known `Bundle:Controller:view` format to an absolute path

Comment: I tried __DIR__ . '/../../ArchiveBundle/Resources/views/ but it just throws me an error that it cant find the template. I know it's there. Maybe the ../ is not allowed here? I also tried specifying the full path manually (based on the format of DIR) which in my case is '/var/www/biztv/src/BizTV/ArchiveBundle/Resources/views/ContentTemplate/28/view.html.twig' but I get the same error =(

Answer (score 27):

Within a twig template, you can set the value of a printed variable like this:

```
{% set rendered %}
  {{ var_to_print }}
{% endset %}
```

Comment: I was surprised when I tried this. It works in old 1.xx versions and 2.xx versions as well. Not sure about 0.xx versions, but I doubt that those work.

Comment: Wow, this is a real diamond! I was looking for this for a long time.

Answer (score 24):

You can get content form rendered object like this:

```
$this->render('BizTVArchiveBundle:ContentTemplate:Some.html.twig', array())->getContent();
```

Comment: is not working, it says `Call to a member function getContent() on string`

Answer (score 8):

That is because `$this->render()` returns a `Response` object.
Instead of `$this->render()`, use `$this->renderView()`.

Comment: This seems to work although there is no mention of renderView in [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#response)