# JSONResponse in html modal tag using Symfony

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, rendering, bootstrap-modal

thanks for your time.

I'm trying to load a form with data to edit in a Bootstrap Modal.
I am able to load the JsonResponse from my controller, but it display the raw JSON code.

My controller JsonResponse :

```
    //more code
    $response = new JsonResponse(
                array(
            'message' => 'Success!',
            'form' => $this->renderView('EPAdminBundle:Admin:formmmm.html.twig', array(
                'event' => $event,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ))), 200);

      return $response;
```

I'm trying to render the form in this view.

View test.html.twig :

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ path('ep_admin_test_form', {'slug': 'fete-1'}) }}" data-target="#modalForm" id="test">Click me !</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="loadHere">
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script in the test.html.twig :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#test").on("click", function () {
            url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
                    if (jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('form')) {
                        $('#loadHere').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.form);
                    }
                    $('.form_error').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
                } else {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The formmmm.html.twig loaded as JSON :

```html
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modification de l'évènement :</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="statusMsg"></p>
    <div class="well row">
         {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal col-lg-12'}}) }} 

//more code
//Used the snipped because it had trouble displaying the code
```

My goal is to load in the pre-filled form in a modal Bootstrap and edit the data, then send it in a controller through AJAX. So far I'm having trouble decoding JSON in my view and i can't find a solution by myself or on the internet.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: you need to call getContent() after calling render(). Use @Liutas's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956660/how-to-render-twig-output-to-a-variable-for-later-use-symfony2

Comment: This isn't the problem. In my code i use ->renderView, which is equivalent to render()->getContent(). I did it, and it gives me the same JSON answer.

Comment: from the looks of it, the only problem is the form. That's the part you're not getting the resulted HTML.

Comment: enjoy https://blog.intelligentbee.com/2015/01/19/symfony-2-forms-and-ajax/

Comment: It gives more something like this loaded in my modal : [JSON render](http://imgur.com/a/WLWvo). Thanks for your answers.

Comment: That's on what i based my code. I guess i'll start all over it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the tutorial : https://blog.intelligentbee.com/2015/01/19/symfony-2-forms-and-ajax/

Then the script is bugged if i want to load the script.

I have found the solution by myself after some days by using the console and looking through the jqXHR object using the next method :

```
var objs = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jqXHR);
for (var i in objs) {
      console.log(objs[i]);
 }
```

The problem was that jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('form') doesn't exist.

```html
$('#loadHere').html(jqXHR.form);
if (typeof jqXHR.form !== 'undefined') {
    if (jqXHR.hasOwnProperty('form')) {
        $('#loadHere').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.form);
    }
    $('.form_error').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
} else {
    alert('error');
}
```

If anyone has a question, ask and i'll try to help.